# Kendoui dataviz chart tooltip to overlay bootstrap navs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a kendo ui dataviz chart inside a bootstrap navs like this (or something like it) :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-static">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#myTab" data-toggle="tab">Ranking ACT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="myTab" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="myKendoChart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I have a hover that shows the toolip on a series, it goes behind the tab section, hiding part of its content.

How can I set the toolip to be always on top (over) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a z-index very high, 1000 for example and position relative or absolute to the class of tooltip element (if needed) and change the container overflow property to visible => `overflow: visible;`.

Comment: Did you apply it to the correct element? Did you set the position of that element to relative or absolute?

Comment: Kendo sets it to absolute automatically.
I did apply to the correct element i think, i added a style in my html like this:
<style>
    .k-chart .k-tooltip {
        z-index: 1000;
    }

</style>

Comment: Sorry I didn't remember that, so the problem is probably due to the container (<div class="tab-content"> or
    <div id="myTab" class="tab-pane">). Change the container overflow property to visible => overflow: visible;

Comment: Great! Have a nice day